# Show iPhone Contacts Before Opening MFMessageComposeViewController (SMS)

Tags: ios, sms, contacts

I have `MFMessageComposeViewController` working within my app, allowing a user to send an SMS message.

Currently, the user has to tap the `"+"` symbol to add recipients. I would like to present the Contacts list first, allow the user to select multiple Contacts, and then they tap a button and are shown the `MFMessageComposeViewController` with the recipients populated.

Is there a way to do this through the existing `MFMessageComposeViewController` functions, or would I need to implement this myself?